# Apple Maps UI Design: Search Bar, Nearby Buttons, and Table View

Tags: swift, user-interface, maps, uistoryboard, apple-maps

I'm not sure how to build a UI design and MVC architecture that matches the Apple Maps App.  1. How should I setup my UI in main.storyboard? 2. How should I structure my code?

I could include screenshot of my many attempts of the UI design and code, but I think it would only be a distraction for you all.  Thanks for your help!

See screenshots:

[Apple Maps UI - pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sp4aH.jpg)
[Apple Maps UI - pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2i1K.jpg)

Comment: Please checkout https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
This question is not exactly related to programming as such and you lack a code example and error.

Answer (score -1):

A very good channel in Youtube that will help you a lot is the following:

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCuP2vJ6kRutQBfRmdcI92mA

Now, you have a long road ahead of you, if you want to build the UI in the attached pictures. So better focus on improving your skills first, in my humble opinion.

Comment: Thanks, I've watched several of his videos.  I'm trying to build my final "build your own app" for my Udaicty iOS Nanodegree.  Struggling to create a data model that is similar to the Apple Maps App.